# SolrCloud is detecting non-existing nodes

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am having an interesting situation with SolrCloud. Basically, I dont know why, but Solr instance, which does not in the cloud normally, is displayed on SolrCloud page and also visible in `live_nodes` path in Zookepeer.

Here are details about the situation:

I have one Solr instance, running as a standalone application on a virtual machine, located on a remove machine. We will call it `virtual1` from now on.

This is the script for running it:

```
java
-server
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseCompressedStrings
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-d64
-Xmx4096m
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=remotehost -jar start.jar
```

this instance is running on port 8983, so when you go to `virtual1:8983`, you see the classical admin page of solr. the rest of the configs are all the same with example solr, which comes with solr distrubutions.

Then, on my local machine (will be called `local` from now on), I am running my zookeeper servers on ports `2181` and `2182`

then for adding my solr instances to the cloud, I am simply running one instance on my local machine and two more on `virtual1` and the scripts for starting them as are below:

Solr Instance on my local:

```
java -Dbootstrap_conf=true -DzkHost=zkhost:2181 -Djetty.port=8984 -jar start.jar
```

Solr Instances on remote:

```
java -DzkHost=zkhost:2181 -Djetty.port=8985 -jar start.jar
java -DzkHost=zkhost:2182 -Djetty.port=8986 -jar start.jar
```

Until here, there are no exceptions or errors in either Solr or Zookeeper logs.

When I check `virtual1:8985 and virtual1:8986` they are all running, as well as the instance on my local.

But when I check the cloud (both from Solr admin page and also zookeeper CLI). i can only see `local:8983` and `virtual1:8983` in the cloud, while `virtual1:8985 and virtual1:8986` are not added at all... The weird point is that `virtual1:8983` doesnt know anything about Zookeeper servers as you can see from the starting scripts above.

In addition the facts above, I have tried another thing. On another virtual machine(`virtual2`) which is running on the same hard machine with `virtual1`
, I have created Solr instances with:

```
java -DzkHost=zkhost:2181 -Djetty.port=8985 -jar start.jar
java -DzkHost=zkhost:2182 -Djetty.port=8986 -jar start.jar
```

So in this case I will have instances as `virtual2:8985 and virtual2:8986`, which should be in the cloud. But it doesnt happen... I can only see `virtual2:8983`, which does not exists in real. It simply shows the standalone Solr's port, which is running on `virtual1`.

can anyone explain why is this happening?

Answer (score -1):

You should try to remove zookeeper data and specify -Dbootstrap_confdir=/path/to/conf/dir which pushes configs and node state to zookeeper. Also if you're running zookeeper ensemble check their state (leader or follower, or if there is no connections to node) with

```
echo stat | nc zk_host zk_port
```

And you can use zkCli.sh to see cluster state with

```
get /clusterstate.json
```

And show zookeeper config, they should look something like this:

```
clientPort=2181 (2182 for second instance)
server.1=zk_host:2888:3888
server.2=zk_host:2888:3888
```

And check both Solr and Zookeeper logs for the successfull connections.